# Global Protect Linux - how to change the default browser for SAML login

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, browser

I have two Microsoft email accounts in my working organization, every time GlobalProtect connects, it prompts Chrome(default browser) out to ask me to login. and I use the old account to login.

Now, the new account is created due to some internal process, and I want to use that in Chrome and move old account login into another browser, for example Firefox. How can I do that?

I changed `/opt/paloaltonetworks/globalprotect/pangps.xml`, change this line to `no`:

```
<default-browser>no</default-browser>
```

and restarted, but it still use Chrome.

How to change the behavior of default browser SAML login so that it uses the browser I want?

Ubuntu 18

EDIT: now I have completely moved to new laptop and solely use the new account, so I cannot test solution anymore. Anyone else with the same problem please use this question to exchange ideas.